# Why do most users have no picture in their profile?

Tags: discussion, community, avatar

Is our site different from the other StackExchange sites in the lack of users' pictures?

Comment: I wonder if we have a higher-than-normal-for-SE proportion of users for whom this is their first SE site.  If so, conventions from other sites might be slower to enter the collective consciousness.

Comment: @Monica, I believe that we do. See [this chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1073873#1073873) (about 10 messages) for some data based on Area51 commitment stats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To your second question, it appears that the answer is yes.

I looked at the first page-worth of users (top 36 reputation-earners in the past month) on our site and a few semi-randomly chosen others. Here's how many photos including the user's (I presume) face I found on each:

- Jewish Life and Learning - 5
- Stack Overflow - 16
- Personal Finance and Money - 9
- Fitness and Nutrition - 18
- Literature - 12

I can only speculate about why this would be. Perhaps it's related to Judaism's emphasis on modesty.

Comment: I don't know whether the OP was asking about user-set avatars (as opposed to default) or specifically about those that include an actual picture of the user. (Mine, for example, is the former but not the latter.) This answer address the latter question; numbers for the former are: JLL, 18; SO, 25; Money, 20; Fitness, 24; Lit, 24. If there were statistical significance in all this, I might say that that's support for your conjecture that modesty is the reason.

Comment: I think you just called me immodest... :-)

Comment: @Michael, I'm just trying to explain a sociological phenomenon.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of our users like to remain anonymous, including myself. Putting up a picture would defeat that purpose...

Whether we have a greater anonymity rate than other sites is hard to tell, but if we do, "why?" would be a fair question to [ask](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: "Why" is the question in the title. It's a fair question to ask, but answers can only speculate.

Comment: @IsaacMoses true, but I've yet to see an anonymous user on our site with a real picture (although we do have some "first-namers")

Comment: OK, I guess it should be possible to make some verifiable claims.